# Scheduling and Resource Management in OS

Tags: operating-systems

The below text is taken from the book : Operating Systems: Internals and Design Principles by William Stallings, 8th edition, page 68.

> Scheduling and Resource Management
>
> A key responsibility of the OS is to manage the various resources
> available to it (main memory space, I/O devices, processors) and to
> schedule their use by the various active processes. Any resource
> allocation and scheduling policy must consider three factors:
>
> - Fairness: Typically, we would like all processes that are competing for the use of a particular resource to be given approximately equal
>   and fair access to that resource. This is especially so for jobs of
>   the same class, that is, jobs of similar demands.
> - Differential responsiveness: On the other hand, the OS may need to discriminate among different classes of jobs with different service
>   requirements. The OS should attempt to make allocation and scheduling
>   decisions to meet the total set of requirements. The OS should also
>   make these decisions dynamically. For example, if a process is waiting
>   for the use of an I/O device, the OS may wish to schedule that process
>   for execution as soon as possible to free up the device for later
>   demands from other processes.
> - Efficiency: The OS should attempt to maximize throughput, minimize response time, and, in the case of time sharing, accommodate as many
>   users as possible. These criteria conflict; finding the right balance
>   for a particular situation is an ongoing problem for OS research.

I cant understand the meaning of Differential Responsiveness, can somebody please explain it to me ?

Comment: related https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_operating_system

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not every job that a computer has to do has equal importance or urgency.

An example is different I/O devices which work at different speeds. A network interface, for example, generally runs at a much higher bandwidth than a keyboard or mouse, so servicing the network interface would typically be a higher priority task than servicing a keyboard. But, on the other hand, servicing a real-time clock might be even higher priority than those, so that the computer keeps good time.

This is even more critical in real-time systems, where for some computations, a late answer is a wrong answer. An obvious example is software that controls a physical device, such as in a vehicle control system; a late response could mean catastrophe.